# Regular Expression pattern for Java Exceptions

Tags: java, regex

I have a function which takes a string of log messages. I want to determine whether a passed message is of an Exception pattern so I can wrap with rendering color.

Do anyone know if there's a `Regular Expression` pattern to handle this?

Edited

Comment: What does a logged exception look like? What do you want to match from it? What have you tried?

Comment: with 2K reputation you should be able to write a better question.

Comment: Are you talking about matching the output from `Exception.toString()`?

Comment: @MK. What do you mean by a better question? This forum has been built to allow editors to step in where a specific question doesn't stand up enough or to ask for clarity when neccesary, but not to use it as tool for F patronizing. Does 2K makes me guru or God.

Comment: @Bitmap your question is not well written.  I don't know if there is a non-patronizing way to say that.

Comment: Which portion of the question is ill-writen?! Point it out, make suggestions if possible - you seems to think SO reputation makes one a psychic.

Answer (score 0):

You can write anything you want in exception trace...  so no, not in this generality.

Answer (score 0):

It would be rather gnarly ... to say the least.

Another idea might be to change the log appender's layout to include the colour markup in the log file.  Or maybe output the logs as (well-formed) XML records that you can then render for display using XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

The names of exception classes are traditionally suffixed with "Exception" or "Error", so you could look for that, but this is not a requirement.  If you controll all exceptions (or at least know that all possible exceptions thrown will conform to this guideline), you can do a regex as mentioned above